# drupal add class to form-item if error on form to all forms

Tags: 7, theming

I just want to add class to .form-item if there is error on form i used the following code but its not working.

```
function semanticUI_form_element($variables) {
  if (isset($element['#parents']) && form_get_error($element)) {
    $attributes['class'][] = array('error1');
  }
  if(form_get_error($element)){
    $attributes['class'][] = array('error1');
  }

  if (!empty($element['#required'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test';
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this your actual code or have you simplified it for inclusion here?  for example, you don't appear to define `$element` which you need to grab out of `$variables['element']`...

Comment: sorry forget to mention this $element = $variables['element']; i used this.

Answer (score 2):

If you copy the `theme_form_element()` function out of `includes/form.inc` and into your theme's `template.php` file, re-name it to match your theme, and change the initial setting of `$attributes['class']` accordingly:

```
  if (form_get_error($variables['element'])) {
    $attributes['class'] = array('form-item', 'da-error');
  } else {
    $attributes['class'] = array('form-item'); 
  }
```

...this will put a `da-error` class in the overall `<div>` wrapping this element.